# Angular 5 Reactive form doesn't create ID level on Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I had a Template-driven form (using ngModel) and I'm trying to change it into a Reactive form. This form submits data to a Firebase Database.

Before (template-driven) the data were inserted properly into Firebase, creating an ID for each object sent, like this:

[image]

However, when I changed into Reactive form, sometimes the data are inserted without any ID, as it's shown below:

[image]

I have not been able to figure out a pattern when this happens, nor do I find any error in the code that can justify this behavior.

service.component.html

```
 <form [formGroup]="f" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <input type="hidden" id="$key" formControlName="$key">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nome">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" formControlName="nome">
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="preco">Price</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="preco" formControlName="preco">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tempo">Time</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" id="tempo" formControlName="tempo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="f?.invalid">Save</button>
  </form>
```

service.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Servico } from './servico';

export class ServiceComponent implements OnInit {

  f: FormGroup;

  userId: string;
  $key: string;
  value: any;
  servicos: FirebaseListObservable<Servico[]>;
  servico: FirebaseObjectObservable<Servico>;  

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, 
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private fb: FormBuilder) { 

    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) this.userId = user.uid
        this.servicos = db.list(`servicos/${this.userId}`);
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.f = this.fb.group({
      $key: new FormControl(''),
      nome: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      preco: this.fb.control(''),
      tempo: this.fb.control('')
    })
  }

  submit() {       
    if (this.f.controls.$key.value == null)
      {
        this.db.list(`servicos/${this.userId}/`).push({
          nome: this.f.controls.nome.value,
          preco: this.f.controls.preco.value,
          tempo: this.f.controls.tempo.value
        }).then(() => {
            this.f.controls.nome.setValue('');
            this.f.controls.preco.setValue('');
            this.f.controls.tempo.setValue('');
            this.f.controls.$key.setValue(null);
          });
        }else{
          this.db.object(`servicos/${this.userId}/` + this.f.controls.$key.value).update({
            nome: this.f.controls.nome.value,
            preco: this.f.controls.preco.value,
            tempo: this.f.controls.tempo.value
          }).then(() => {
            this.f.controls.nome.setValue('');
            this.f.controls.preco.setValue('');
            this.f.controls.tempo.setValue('');
            this.f.controls.$key.setValue(null);
          }));
        }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that your variable `this.f.controls.$key.value` is being set incorrectly to an empty string, and that's what's causing the data to appear in the wrong place. Since an empty string isn't `null` then your `if (this.f.controls.$key.value == null)` will be falsey, and the `else` will trigger...

```
} else {
                                         // This is an empty string
                                                         \/  
                                                         \/  
    this.db.object(`servicos/${this.userId}/` + this.f.controls.$key.value).update({
      ...values...
    }).then(() => {
      ...etc...
    }));
  }
```

Which means your `update` call is actually just directed towards:

```
this.db.object(`servicos/${this.userId}/
```

To confirm this is the issue, try hardcoding a value instead of `this.f.controls.$key.value` in your update call, I suspect the weird behavior will go away. You'll need to find another way to get the correct key/path.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it seems you are right about the reason why it's not working sometimes. I found that the issue happens always the page is displayed for the first time. Maybe the issue is before the `submit()` function?

Comment: It's definitely before the `submit()` function, the problem is related to the line `$key: new FormControl('')`... you are assigning the variable `$key` to a hidden input field - and I don't see any code that populates that input with a value... so the value of $key never changes, so `$key.value` will remain an empty string.

Comment: So, please update your answer writing this, because I assigned the variable `$key = 'null'` in FormControl and it worked!

Comment: I changed this line to `$key: new FormControl(null),` and now it works. Your answer helped me to find the solution.